# Does Visual Studio support a "shortcut hierarchy"?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I have Visual Studio 2013 and ReSharper. I like to have F12 bound to ReSharper's "Go To Implementation" command, but it is not always an option. So when there is no option to go to the implementation, I want F12 to revert back to the Visual Studio default of "Go To Definition" (where there is a definition). Is this setup possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not. A keyboard shortcut can only be bound to a single command for a single scope. That is, you can bind a keyboard shortcut to one command for the text editor, but another command for, say, the XAML designer. There's no way to "fall back" to another command (how would you know when to fall back?)